# How to trigger a Symbian C++ application within a J2ME application for Nokia phones using J2ME API?

Tags: symbian, nokia, java-me, heap-memory, external-process

Anyone knows how to trigger a Symbian C++ application using any J2ME API call? I have a J2ME application that needs a customized photo taking application in Symbian C++. The reason for separating into two applications is because J2ME has a limit in heap size and the J2ME needs to know the path of photo after taking it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards,
Kenny

Comment: Have you tried it in j2me and actually run out of heap space? Recent devices should have enough heap memory in J2me to handle taking a picture, even in fairly high resolution.

Comment: Hi Ola, my current J2ME application needs to take highest resolution images and send it over the internet. It seems that viewing the images is not possible as the heap size is not enough. Compression on the images might take up the heap size as well and on top of the networking part. Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen a j2me app on the Sony Ericsson Satio handling 12 mpixel images with viewfinder, that's why I asked. Maybe you use case requires more memory. What device are you targeting? How big are the highest reolution images?

Comment: If you are sure you need Symbian OS C++ to take the picture, why do you need to use J2ME for the rest of the application? Although the loopback socket solution kgiannakakis suggested is technically correct, it's just an awful ugly inefficient thing once you understand the Symbian/Java threading model. Although JSR-211 could theorically help you, I don't think the Java side of it has been correctly integrated with the native Symbian OS C++ application architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at APIBridge on Forum Nokia: http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/d697a64f-ddae-4937-8151-be157b542d26/ApiBridge.html

Designed specifically for MIDP apps to access services provided in the Symbian C++ environment.

Comment: Great, this is what I looking for. Thanks a lot KevinD and all of you!

Comment: As suggested APIBridge is best way to solve this kind of problem. same way you can create your own "Plugins" and make a request to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API for doing that. One thing you could try is to have your two applications communicate over a socket interface. For example the Symbian application could set up a socket server at localhost and the J2ME application would connect to it. I am not sure that this is possible in a phone's environment however. It could also have other implications as well, such as having to sign your applications.

Comment: Hi Kgiannakakis, your idea is great. But was wondering whether we can run the symbian app in background. If there are two J2ME applications running at the same time, does it share the same heap size? I thought of calling external J2ME application from another J2ME application. Tried many ways but seems not able to trigger it to run.
Thanks.

Comment: J2me apps on Symbian S60 does not share heap, unless if they are in the same midlet suite. On the other hand one of the apps may be closed down if the system runs out of memory. JSR-211 is a good way to communicate between midlets.